# SkScene not displaying all children and incorrect node count

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have my SKScene, but for some reason, it is not displaying all its children only some of them. The only child that's displayed is the one used to show the background image as well as a while rectangular outline that appears [image of rectangle outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYagL.png) to be at the anchor point (0.5,0.5) (I am new to stack). The node count only shows three but I have added these children : (levelbg is for the background image abd I have set the zpositon to ensure its at the bottom of everything and I also tried to clear the derived data. Im wondering if someone could help me thank you (and aplogies for code I am doing this so I learn more about spritekit)_

```
  //levelbg
    levelBg.zPosition = 0.0
    levelBg.position = CGPoint(x:frame.minX,y:frame.minY)
    levelBg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    self.addChild(levelBg);
    //sword button
    swordButton.zPosition = 1.0;
    swordButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - 200, y: 530);
    swordButton.run(SKAction.sequence([waitFade,moveItem,fadeIn]));
    self.addChild(swordButton);
    //convoBg
    convoBg = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 425, width: Int(frame.maxX), height: 175))
    convoBg.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 400)
    convoBg.fillColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.15, green: 0.31, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1.0);
    convoBg.strokeColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0);
    convoBg.lineWidth = 10;
    convoBg.zPosition = 2.0;
    addChild(convoBg);

    
    //characters
    mainHero.position = CGPoint(x:frame.minX + 100, y: frame.midY);
    mainHero.name = "hero";
    mainHero.zPosition = 2.0;
    mainHero.alpha = 0.0;
    mainHero.run(SKAction.sequence([waitFade,moveItem,fadeIn]));
    mainHero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: mainHero.texture!, size: (mainHero.texture!.size()));
    mainHero.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true;
    mainHero.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = contactType.heroType.rawValue;
    mainHero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = contactType.rockType.rawValue;
    mainHero.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = contactType.rockType.rawValue;
    mainHero.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false;
    mainHero.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false;
    self.addChild(mainHero);
//arrows
    left.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 45, y: 540);
    left.zPosition = 1.0;
    left.alpha = 0.0;
    left.run(SKAction.sequence([waitFade,moveItem,fadeIn]));
    self.addChild(left);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by resizing my view and readding my nodes in again